# How can I make R read my environmental variables?

Tags: linux, r, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, environment-variables

I am running R on EC2 spot instances and I need R to terminate the instance and cancel the spot request once the script has run.

For that I have set the "Request ID" into an environmental variable in `/.bashrc` and my plan was to simply call the following code into R once the script is ready

```
system("ec2-cancel-spot-instance-requests $SIR")
```

The issue I am having is that R is not "seeing" the same environmental variables I seen when I type `env` from outside R thus the command is not working.

I have checked and if I set my environmental variables at `/etc/environment` R is able to see those variables, but here is the other problem. As those variables are dynamic (the instance ID and the request ID is different each time a spot instance is created), I am running a script to create them in the form of:

```
export SIR=`cat /etc/ec2_instance_spot_id.txt`
```

Where that file contains the dynamic ID

So, how can I insert "dynamic" environmental variables into `/etc/environment` ? Or, how can I make R read the environmental variables at `/.bashrc`?

Comment: I found that variables in ~/.profile were accessible from Sys.getenv(), but not from ~/.bashrc.  I had to do `source ~/.profile`, then `R` from a terminal to get it working after adding new variables.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You want `Sys.getenv()` as in `Sys.getenv("PATH")`, say.

Or for your example, try

```
SIR <- Sys.getenv("SIR")   
system(paste("ec2-cancel-spot-instance-requests",  SIR))
```

As for setting variables at startup, see `help(Startup)` to learn about `~/.Renvironment` etc

Comment: Thanks a lot Dirk for your time. The issue I am having is that when I do for example `names(s <- Sys.getenv())` then `SIR` is not there, when I do `SIR <- Sys.getenv("SIR")` there is nothing in SIR, but when I exit R and I do `env` that list of environmental variables is totally different than the one I get when I `Sys.getenv()` and there I can see SIR and others I need. I will give a look at `Renvironment`, thanks a lot again.

Comment: OK, this is shameful.Why do I want to read the environmental variables within R if I already created 2 files with the request ID and instance ID? I can just get the value of those files and perform my task... this does not explain why R was not seeing the same environmental variables as I see when I quit R, but will get me going! Thanks for the inspiration!

Comment: I made this work by using `Sys.setenv()` and basically copying my environmental variables from outside R to R. Although this makes my script work, I wish I could understand why there is whole set of different environmental variables witting R

Answer (score 21):

My approach was this: I had project-level environment variables stored in a `.env` file. To make it accessible in R, I used

```
> readRenviron(".env")
```

Then to access a specific variable

```
> Sys.getenv("RDS_UID")
```

And it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 18):

Using `Sys.getenv()` you see all variables listed in the current environment.

However, they are different from those used in your current shell, for example specified in .profile.

To set the variables for R create a `.Renviron` file in your home directory and write there

```
MYDIRECTORY="/home/wherever"
```

After restarting R you will be able to access this variable with

```
Sys.getenv("MYDIRECTORY")
```

Comment: My home directory does not have the .Renviron file, and inside R it returns an old value of the environment variable after I have change the value several days ago. Could not figure out where R gets the old value and not returning the new value.

Answer (score 0):

A more complete approach:

Make a file like `myenvs/.Renviron` with contents:

```
USERNAME="my_username"
PASSWORD="StrongPassword"
```

Then, load and use in R like:

```r
readRenviron("myenvs/.Renviron")
username <- Sys.getenv("USERNAME")
password <- Sys.getenv("PASSWORD")
```