# .Renviron variables not found when Rscript run from powershell?

Tags: r, renviron

I have an R script that runs perfectly when run from Rstudio. It uses an `.Renviron` file to provide environment variables which are visible in `Sys.getenv()` (so I know it works).

However, when I run the exact same script via powershell, the R script mysteriously doesn't find those environment variables (I confirmed this by `print(Sys.getenv())` - the environment variables provided through `.Renviron` are nowhere to be seen.

#### Question

Why aren't the `.Renviron` variables being found when the R script is run from powershell (as opposed to when the script is run in RStudiom, where everything works)

#### What I've tried

The `.Renviron` file is currently saved in `"C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/.Renviron"`

Inspecting `normalizePath(Sys.getenv('R_HOME'))` returns `"C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.6.0"`, so I also tried putting `.Renviron` there. No luck

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291418/how-can-i-make-r-read-my-environmental-variables) I also tried `Sys.getenv("C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/.Renviron")`, but again no luck

Comment: Yep - can also confirm that with WIN 10 `.Renviron` located in R_USER directory (ie `C:\\Users\\Username`) is not being read when starting R from the command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what worked for me

```r
path_to_Renviron_file <- "C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/.Renviron"
readRenviron(path_to_Renviron_file)
```

Comment: This is incorrect, R *does* load the `~/.REnviron` file, and the file shouldn’t be loaded explicitly.

Comment: @KonradRudolph the line fixed the issue. If not for the reason above, I am not sure why? Do you know? Can you test it on your machine, I am not sure why it would be any different for you. I am running windows server 2019 on EC2 (`Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Base - ami-0bbdf9279190cdd33`)

Comment: See my answer. The problem with such workaround fixes is that they don’t address the actual problem and may thus break in unexpected ways once something changes. And using hard-coded absolute paths is a big no-no anyway — part of the reason is explained here: https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2017/12/workflow-vs-script/

Comment: I think the real problem is that there is no good way to discover what R is really doing.    There is no explicit environment path variable to inspect to see where it is actually looking and no way to get feedback from R to allow one to have it display which files it is or is not reading.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck This is a very good point. Debugging these issues is a real pain.

Comment: Agree with @G.Grothendieck.

Comment: I have come across 3 difference locations on Windows `.REnviron` could get read from:

---

1. `C:/Users/Username` if script run from Git Bash

2. `C:/Users/Username/Documents` if script run from RStudio

3. `C:/Windows/System32` if script run with RStudio TaskscheduleR addin

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem: `.Renviron` files were being completely ignored on Windows.
I thought that what finally worked was reinstalling R (I had R 3.6, installed R 4.0).

But it turns out I was wrong. The magic sauce is adding `--cd-to-userdocs` to the `R.exe` or `Rscript.exe` command.
I couldn't find documentation for this option anywhere, and it doesn't show up in command line parameters help, but it works.

Comment: This workaround is "ok" but I often do not want to change to the `userdocs`  (`My Documents`) folder when starting R from the command line - so not really a satisfying situation, is it.

Answer (score 1):

RScript performs the same initialisation as normal R, unless this is specifically disabled with command line options (`--no-environ`). The `.Renviron` and `.Rprofile` files are searched for in different locations, in descending order of priority:

1. In the current working directory
2. In the user’s home directory
3. In the R home directory (`R_HOME`)

[The documentation gives more details.](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Startup.html)

Since you’ve tried to change the file in locations (2) and (3) without success, it stands to reason that you have *another* `.Renviron` file in your current working directory from which you are launching `Rscript`.

Comment: I like the idea of best practice (i.e. avoiding absolute paths). But I am sure there is no extra `.Renviron` file(s) - just one. (the `.R` script is definitely being run with `Rscript "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\myscript.R`

Comment: Also, if I put `print(Sys.getenv())` either side of the call to `readRenviron()` line, I can see the two list of environment variables. The first doesn't have the ones declared in  `.Renviron`, and the second one does. I don't think the duplicate `.Renviron` file is the cause..

Comment: @user5783745 *Where* are you running this command from, though? What does `cd` print? Is there an .Renviron file there? And what is `Rscript`? Is it maybe an alias to the *actual* `Rscript` binary, which sets the `--no-environ` option? If neither of these is the case I suggest reinstalling R because your installation appears to be broken.

Comment: @ I have a shortcut in `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` which points to a directory on the desktop with only a couple of files (.git and the rscript - 100% sure there is no `.Renviron` file there). Also, I have hidden files ticked (just to rule out another possible cause)

Comment: `Rscript` does indeed point to the actual `Rscript` binary. Are you saying it ignores `.Renviron` by default?

Comment: @user5783745 No, on the contrary. I’m saying that it *doesn’t* ignore `.Renviron` unless told to explicitly. Does the shortcut have any command line options saved in its configuration?

Comment: Okay cool. No, it's basically a fresh install of windows server 2019. I haven't tinkered with anything, just installed R/Rstudio, put an r script on there (from a cloned repo), made an `.Renviron` file and that's it.

Comment: Does this issue have a solution? I am experiencing the same problem on Windows 10 with a fresh install of R 4.02.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same with R 4.1 on Windows 10 when trying to use Rscript from the command line.