# R get environment variable or default value

Tags: r

**In R how can I get an environment variable value, or a default value if the variable is not set?**

I'm looking for something of the form:

```
Sys.getenv("FOO_KEY").withDefault("barValue")
```

There is [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291418/how-can-i-make-r-read-my-environmental-variables) which only asks how to get an environment variable that is sure to exist.

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Comment: Is there are a reason you are avoiding something like `ifelse(Sys.getenv("FOO_KEY")=="", "defaultValue", Sys.getenv("FOO_KEY"))` ? It has to do the function call twice which isn't ideal in terms of performance (and technically creates a race condition) but mostly that's not going to matter. If it does then you could do `val  <- Sys.getenv("FOO_KEY"); if(val=="") val  <- "defaultValue"`, or similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass the default value to the `unset` argument:

```r
Sys.getenv("FOO_KEY", unset = "barValue")
```

or simply

```r
Sys.getenv("FOO_KEY", "barValue")
```